# Implode não está funcionando direito

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, mysqli

Eu estou usando este código

```
    include_once('../conexao.php'); 
    $query = "SELECT titulo FROM info";
    $result = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
    $titulo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tp_Control" placeholder="Digite o título" value=<?php echo implode($titulo) ?>>
```

O código acima pega o título da página que está no banco de dados e coloca na caixa de texto, mas toda vez que eu vou verificar o caixa de texto o título não está sendo mostrado todo, depois do espaço ele some, mas quando eu olho para o título da página ele amostra todo, sem o corte.
E o código que eu uso para o título é este.

```
<title><?php echo implode($titulo) ?></title>
```

[image: É isso que sempre acontece]

Alguém tem idéia do que pode ser?

Comment: Que tal experimentar abraçar o value do input com aspas?  .... value="<?php echo implode($titulo) ?>">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O input está sendo carregado da seguinte forma:
(observe que a palavra Automatica está em vermelho o que significa se tratar de um atributo)

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="tp_Control" placeholder="Digite o título" 
value=Lavagem Automatica>
```

observe a propriedade value/valor `value=Lavagem Automatica`

O problema é a falta de aspas no `value=" "` ou value=' ', ele está tratando a palavra `Automatica` como se fosse um atributo do campo texto.

O correto é:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="tp_Control" placeholder="Digite o título" 
value="<?php echo implode($titulo) ?>">
```

o que vai resultar:
(observe que a palavra Automatica Não está mais em vermelho o que significa Não se tratar de um atributo)

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="tp_Control" placeholder="Digite o título" 
 value="Lavagem Automatica">
```

> Atributos definem um comportamento desejado ou indicam propriedades adicionais do elementos. A maioria dos atributos exigem um valor. No HTML, o valor pode ser adicionado sem aspas, caso não possua espaços (name=valor), ou deve ser adicionado com aspas simples ou duplas (name='valor tal' ou name="valor tal")

Comment: Eu ainda estou aprendendo PHP, muito obrigado pela ajuda, e muito obrigado pela explicação, foi excelente.